# how do i print out multiple elements from an array in one go? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, c++17

I have an array:

```
char testarray[5] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'};
```

now i want to print out only 'A' & 'B'
is there something like testarray[0:3] like in python?

Comment: `std::span(testarray, testarray + 2)` in C++20.

Comment: do you mean `[0:2]` ? `[0:3]` would be {A,B,C}, no?

Comment: Note that if you were using a `std::string` instead of a `char[]`, you could directly use [substr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
std::cout << std::string_view(testarray, 2);
```

Comment: @spartacus1000 The headers which declare/define `std::cout` and `std::string_view`. See their documentation.

Comment: there is no std header for string_view or span?

Comment: Go to cppreference, search for those symbols, and see what headers it says to include. also check you are compiling in a new enough C++ Standard version to have them at all. It would be good if the answer specified those conditions.

Comment: [`std::cout`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) and [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more general solution, you could think about an update to C++20 update which has now the ranges-library:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges

With it you can write somethink like this:

```
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  char testarray[] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'};
  for(auto& i : std::ranges::subrange(&testarray[0], &testarray[2])){
    std::cout << i << ' ';
  }  
}
```

For simple "memory-ranges" `std::span<T>` or `std::string_view` are just fine, too.